# setTimeout event doesnt work propery when same program is open in two different tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have tried to do image slider with two images but when i am opening same page in two tabs or if i minimize Firefox and maximize again the images slider is blinking and not working properly. Hide and show classes use setTimeout method and they are placed inside the fade class which also uses setTimeout method.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .image1 {
                height: 300;
                left: 181px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 103px;
                width: 300;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var a = 1;
            var flg = 0,
                flg2 = 0;

            function fade() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (flg2 == 0) {
                        hide();
                        flg2 = 1;
                        fade();
                    } else {
                        show();
                        flg2 = 0;
                        fade();
                    }
                }, 3000);

            }
            function hide() {
                document.getElementById("img1").style.opacity = a;
                document.getElementById("img2").style.opacity = (1 - a);
                if (a > 0) 
                    a = a - 0.1;
                else 
                    flg = 1;

                if (flg == 0) 
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        hide();
                    }, 50);
                else 
                    flg = 0;
                }
            function show() {
                document.getElementById("img1").style.opacity = a;
                document.getElementById("img2").style.opacity = (1 - a);
                if (a < 1.0) 
                    a = a + 0.1;
                else 
                    flg = 1;
                if (flg == 0) 
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        show();
                    }, 50);
                else 
                    flg = 0;
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="fade()">
        <img class="image1" height="225" id="img1" src="img/image1.jpg" style="z-index:100" width="225"/>
        <img class="image1" height="225" id="img2" src="img/image2.jpg" style="z-index:1" width="225"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When asking for help with your code, please take the time to format your code *readably*, using proper indentation and such.

Comment: I can't reproduce, can you please provide more details? Is this on a certain version of Firefox/OS? I'm on Firefox 24 on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the code is entirely correct here. It looks like an incorrect use of setTimeout. Perhaps setInterval would be more fitting?

Are you open to using a library such as jQuery? That would take care of a lot of your code

```
//-- our global image references
var img1, img2;

//-- our global interval id, in case we need to stop/start animation 
//-- via clearInterval(intervalId)
var intervalId;

//-- start animation on document load
$(document).ready(function() {
    //-- set image references to appropiate image ids
    img1 = $('#img1');
    img2 = $('#img2');

    //-- start animation loop
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        //-- using jquery's :visible check show/hide appropriately 
        if (img1.is(':visible')) {
            img1.fadeOut();
            img2.fadeIn();
        } else {
            img1.fadeIn();
            img2.fadeOut();
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dboots/3AenB

Comment: setInterval is also giving same problem and i am really interested in doing with javascript. Is there any other way to do it in JavaScript.